# PDO's rowCout() is always zero

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

The `rowCount()` method of PDO always returns zero value, even if there's results, according to:

`count($sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) > 1`

Fromt this PHP code:

```
               $_user = "a";
               $_pass = "b";
         $query = "select user,password from login where user = :user and password = :pass";
    $conn = new PDO("sqlite:" .Config::$db_file);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $sth = $conn->prepare($query);
    $sth->bindParam(':user', $_user);
    $sth->bindParam(':pass', $_pass);
    $sth->execute();
    $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    echo "rowCount() = ",$sth->rowCount(),"\n";
    echo 'count($result) = ', count($result), "\n";
    print_r($result);
```

I get:

```
rowCount() = 0 count($result) = 2 Array ( [user] => a [password] => b )
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Quoting from the docs: If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.

Comment: (Not me, but) probably because this is clearly explained in the manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rowCount()` returns the number of rows affected by the last DELETE, INSERT, or UPDATE statement executed by the corresponding PDOStatement object

it will not work for select statement..

check for manual : [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)